# Creating table while installing module in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I know how to create table in wordpress while installing the plugin. But in opencart i have no idea. Please help to know how can i create a new table while installing the module. I have paste the test.php code that is used to install the module.

```
  <?php
    class ControllerModuletest extends Controller {
        private $error = array(); 

        public function index() {   
            $this->load->language('module/test');

            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

            $this->load->model('setting/setting');

            if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {            
                $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('test', $this->request->post);        

                $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

                $this->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
            }

            $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

            $this->data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
            $this->data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');
            $this->data['text_content_top'] = $this->language->get('text_content_top');
            $this->data['text_content_bottom'] = $this->language->get('text_content_bottom');       
            $this->data['text_column_left'] = $this->language->get('text_column_left');
            $this->data['text_column_right'] = $this->language->get('text_column_right');

            $this->data['entry_product'] = $this->language->get('entry_product');
            $this->data['entry_limit'] = $this->language->get('entry_limit');
            $this->data['entry_image'] = $this->language->get('entry_image');
            $this->data['entry_layout'] = $this->language->get('entry_layout');
            $this->data['entry_position'] = $this->language->get('entry_position');
            $this->data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');
            $this->data['entry_sort_order'] = $this->language->get('entry_sort_order');

            $this->data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
            $this->data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');
            $this->data['button_add_module'] = $this->language->get('button_add_module');
            $this->data['button_remove'] = $this->language->get('button_remove');

            if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
                $this->data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
            } else {
                $this->data['error_warning'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($this->error['image'])) {
                $this->data['error_image'] = $this->error['image'];
            } else {
                $this->data['error_image'] = array();
            }

            $this->data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

            $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
                'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
                'separator' => false
            );

            $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text'      => $this->language->get('text_module'),
                'href'      => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
                'separator' => ' :: '
            );

            $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
                'href'      => $this->url->link('module/test', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
                'separator' => ' :: '
            );

            $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/test', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

            $this->data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

            $this->data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

            if (isset($this->request->post['test_product'])) {
                $this->data['test_product'] = $this->request->post['test_product'];
            } else {
                $this->data['test_product'] = $this->config->get('test_product');
            }   

            $this->load->model('catalog/product');

            if (isset($this->request->post['test_product'])) {
                $products = explode(',', $this->request->post['test_product']);
            } else {        
                $products = explode(',', $this->config->get('test_product'));
            }

            $this->data['products'] = array();

            foreach ($products as $product_id) {
                $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

                if ($product_info) {
                    $this->data['products'][] = array(
                        'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                        'name'       => $product_info['name']
                    );
                }
            }   

            $this->data['modules'] = array();

            if (isset($this->request->post['test_module'])) {
                $this->data['modules'] = $this->request->post['test_module'];
            } elseif ($this->config->get('test_module')) { 
                $this->data['modules'] = $this->config->get('test_module');
            }       

            $this->load->model('design/layout');

            $this->data['layouts'] = $this->model_design_layout->getLayouts();

            $this->template = 'module/test.tpl';
            $this->children = array(
                'common/header',
                'common/footer'
            );

            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
        }

        private function validate() {
            if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/test')) {
                $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
            }

            if (isset($this->request->post['test_module'])) {
                foreach ($this->request->post['test_module'] as $key => $value) {
                    if (!$value['image_width'] || !$value['image_height']) {
                        $this->error['image'][$key] = $this->language->get('error_image');
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!$this->error) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }   
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an install() method in your controller which will run when an install takes place. Simply execute your SQL in there

Comment: yes i came to know about that. but i do not know how to do that. can you make that let me know

Answer (score 3):

[09/08/2013] you can see here http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-page-in-opencart-final/ , hope this help also someone out there concerning this problem..

regards

Answer (score 3):

may be this can help you to create your tables during installation of module.

http://kvcodes.com/2013/11/creating-table-while-installing-module-in-opencart/

Answer (score 3):

Both pages mentioned above have a little mistake:
They are missing `ENGINE...` at the end of the `query`, so fix:

```
$this->db->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "table_Name` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
      `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      `fieldName` text(2) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;");
```